# Calculate sum of $(1^1 + 2^2 +.... + k^k)\bmod m$ in an efficient way??

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, computer-science

I could calculate values of $1^1+\cdots$ for small numbers only. What if $k$ is a very large number maybe in order of $10^9$?

Comment: That would depend on the allowed magnitude of $m$, as another OP pointed out, lately (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365906/efficient-method-to-find-funsumn-pmod-m-where-funsumn-00-11-22). Is that some contest problem?

Comment: Let $S$ be the sum then  $s\equiv 0 \;(mod \;4)$ if $k\equiv 0$ or $k\equiv -1\; mod \;4$ otherwise $s\equiv 1\;(mod \;4)$. (I don't know why)